# WordPress search gives wrong results

Tags: php, wordpress, search

So I have a question about WordPress search, I use get_search_form(); and have written a custom form for it, this works it gives me results, but I noticed that sometimes when I do not have any matching result for search inside post title or post content it still displays some random post, this is random for me because the post has not anything is written inside it that matches search result, so I wanted to know how this happens how this function works.
for example, I have written lorem ipsum text inside the post and searched number 14 and it gave me this post as a result, but there is no 14 written anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The search function in the [WP_Query class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#search-parameters) generates a simple case-insensitive wildcard-based search of the posts table. In SQL, `item LIKE '%searchterm%'` begins and ends with the `%` wildcard character, and searches the item to find the `'searchterm'` text anywhere in it. So the search term `'jewel'` matches `'bejeweled'`, `'jeweler'`, and `'Crown Jewels'` as well as just `'jewel'`.

It ends up looking something like this (simplified).

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM wp_posts
 WHERE (    post_title LIKE '%searchterm%'
         OR post_excerpt LIKE '%searchterm%'
         OR post_content LIKE '%searchterm%' )
```

[Here's the source code.](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/0ea7a38664746f9ad4f402768975c66928817531/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1411)

This query scans your posts table for your `searchterm` anywhere in your posts' content, excerpts, or titles.  (By "posts" I mean posts, pages, media items, and/or custom post types. The search form code chooses which post types to look for.)

This approach to searching generates more false positive results than false negatives. That is, it will very likely find some irrelevant results, and it's less likely to omit relevant results.

I don't know if that's an explanation for your problem. You could try the query above through phpmyadmin and see whether your search function is missing some posts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is useful, I found out what was my problem, So when I said that the number 14 is not written inside the post text I was wrong, it was written inside the image tag which I have added with add media button, so this post content is stored as one big text and for search, it does not matter if this number 14 is written inside image tag or not.  So this is a big problem for me because I have no idea how to avoid this, so what do you suggest I have an idea to write some custom SQL queries and try to work around this problem.

Comment: There are some search plugins, Relevanssi is an example, that do a better job than core search. Might be worth a look.